# MFC Toolbar flyout tooltips

Tags: mfc, tooltip, flyout

I've created a MFC toolbar with toolbar flyouts. If I undock the flyout I get tool-tips but with the flyout docked I do not get any tool tips.

Is this normal or is there something I need to do to support tool-tips on the docked flyout?

Comment: Aren't you missing a `CBRS_TOOLTIPS` in the dwStyle parameter of a Create/CreateEx function?